# Oracle DB 19c installation stuck at the very beginning (Info: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined)

Tags: oracle-19c

I have opened a CMD with Administrator credentials and opened "setup.bat" from there.
But the installation gets stuck at the step "Launching installer". PFB Screenshot. As per the log It's stuck at "INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined..."

I waited for 30-45 minutes before killing the process from task manager and restart PC and retry installation. (Only potential room for issue/conflict I sense is that I had installed Oracle 32-bit client (12c), though uninstalled it using de-install procedure before proceeding with 19c 64-bit installation)

Details:
OS: Windows 11
Oracle DB version: 19c 64-bit

[image]

For the record I have tried below things suggested in community and Stackoverflow

1. Disabling IpV6
2. Disabling all adapters
3. Killing all services relevant to Oracle
4. Cleaning Installation folder in "Temp" directory Under
   "C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Temp
5. Cleaning all files in "Oracle Inventory" under "Program files"
6. Restarting system multiple times after the above steps
7. Copying files into "C:\ins" folder so that
   file path is shorter
8. Flushing the DNS using CMD/

Comment: The installer should generate a log file. Are there any clues there?

Comment: @pmdba, "INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined..." Nothing after that from 1 hour.
I've already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547692/installation-issue-with-oracle12c

Comment: I have already tried 8 different suggestions (edited question to update them)

Comment: So far I didn't get answer for this, I ended up with installing 12C. Though it's outdated, atleast for the need of mine, it was ok to install.

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue in Windows 11 22H2. Was able to resolve with recommendations from Doc ID 2892311.1 and other places combined.

1. The status of Windows Service **Server** and **WorkStation** must be **Running**
2. The network components **Client for Microsoft Network** and **File and
   Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks** must be checked in the
   "Ethernet" properties

And added few arguments while launching installer:

```
setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to comment the entry for the RDBMS on the /etc/oratab, if there was one?